# How to only sum unique values in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table below where I am trying to sum the `order_value` grouping by the unique order number. However, the queries I've tried are returning the entire sum. Expected return is: `34.24` but actual return is `50.37`. How do I get the correct return value?

| Order_Number | Order_Value | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| #1005 | 16.03 | 1 |
| #1005 | 16.03 | 2 |
| #1006 | 18.21 | 3 |

My query:

```
SELECT order_number, 
       SUM(order_value) 
FROM customer_response 
GROUP BY order_number ;
```

I've also tried:

```
SELECT SUM(order_value) 
FROM customer_response 
GROUP BY order_number, order_value

SELECT SUM(order_value) 
FROM customer_response 
GROUP BY order_number
```

This seems like it should be simple but I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar to your query but first extract only distinct rows for `order_number`.

```sql
SELECT order_number, SUM(order_value)
FROM
(
 select distinct on (order_number) *
 from customer_response
) t 
GROUP BY order_number;
```

If you need to get the overall sum for all orders then remove the grouping.

```sql
SELECT SUM(order_value)
FROM
(
 select distinct on (order_number) *
 from customer_response
) t;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b6ab9/2)

**Edit**
Actually since only one row is left per `order_number` summing and grouping is meaningless. So the first query becomes simply

```sql
 select distinct on (order_number) *
 from customer_response;
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
SELECT sum(t.order_avg)
  FROM
     ( SELECT avg(order_value) AS order_avg
         FROM customer_response
        GROUP BY order_number
     ) AS t
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the sum of all distinct `Order_Value`s per `Order_Number`, you can group by `Order_Number` to get the sum in each group and then use `SUM()` window function to get the total:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(SUM(DISTINCT Order_Value)) OVER () total_value
FROM customer_response t
GROUP BY Order_Number;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3a6c9d84a59e9b1dea6eaeb5b9374de1).